# Laravel - HasOneThrough with composite primary key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-one-through

I'm working on an application where persons can view sport games. The tables have composite primary keys. Here is how the relevant attributes of the tables look like:

```
| Game                      | Team        | League_Team    |
|---------------------------|-------------|----------------|
| id (PK)                   | id (PK)     | league_id (PK) |
| league_id (PK)            | name        | team_id (PK)   |
| home_id  (season_team_id) | ...         | season_team_id |
| guest_id (season_team_id) |             | ...            |
| ...                       |             |                |
| ...                       |             |                |
```

So my goal is to get all games together with the specific home and guest team... so it should look like this `Game::with('homeTeam')->with('guestTeam')->....;`

How is it possible to get this kind of relation? I tried `hasOneThrough`, but I don't know how it works with composite primary keys!

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

Models are all empty except of the `$primaryKey` attribute.

Game Model

`protected $primaryKey = ['id', 'league_id'];`
`public function homeTeam() { // ... }`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('basketball_games', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('league_id')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('date');
        $table->unsignedInteger('home_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('guest_id');


        $table->primary(['id','league_id']);

        // Foreign Keys
        $table->foreign('league_id')->references('id')->on('basketball_leagues');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Team Model

Empty

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('basketball_teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

League_Team

`protected $primaryKey = ['league_id','team_id'];`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('basketball_league_teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('league_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('team_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('season_team_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->primary(['league_id','team_id']);

        // Foreign Keys
        $table->foreign('league_id')->references('id')->on('basketball_leagues');
        $table->foreign('team_id')->references('id')->on('basketball_teams');
    });
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and post all the three models and their table migrations

Comment: I added everything to the question!

Comment: @Saly3301 Do you have any suggestions? Thanks